# How to properly set margin for the element in my case

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add bunch of elements inside a div using bootstrap

I have something like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
       //contents
    </div>

    <div id="forms" class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="title">My first app</div> //no stretch 
        <div class="form-group">  //stretch to the edge
            //contents 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> //stretch to the edge
            //contents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is the form-group has default `margin-left:-15px` and `margin-right:-15px` css. so the form looks so stretch to the edge of the `forms` div.

I can manually set `margin:0` to override the css for those forms, but I am not sure if that's the best practice in `bootstrap`. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the container class

Bootstrap:

1. container
2. row(s)
3. col(s)

When you skip one lvl you are most likely to get stuck on the margins
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
       //contents
    </div>

    <div id="forms" class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="title">My first app</div> //no stretch 
        <div class="form-group">  //stretch to the edge
            //contents 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> //stretch to the edge
            //contents
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```